# Use Eyedropper to store appearance

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, eyedropper

I want to have the same appearance (specifically a set opacity for the strokes and fills) for a number of objects.

What I expect to do:

- Create one object and set the appearance as I want it
- Use the eyedropper tool to store this appearance
- When creating another object it will have the same appearance

However, while colour and other attributes are retained, the appearance is not. Thus, what I have to do is the following:

- Create one object and set the appearance as I want it
- Create new object
- Use eyedropper tool (with "copy appearance" checked) to copy the appearance of the first object

This quickly becomes tedious as I have to switch to the eyedropper tool every time I create a new object.

Is there a way of also storing the appearance with the eyedropper tool? Or alternatively, a simpler way of dealing with transparency when creating multiple objects?

Comment: What about pressing the key "i" or creating Graphic Styles?

Comment: "i" is what I am doing now. But essentially I need two clicks and a key press for each object rather than just one click, it seems like there should be a simpler way. Maybe Graphic Styles will be the most robust way, but it's surprising that the eyedropper tool can clone appearance once you have created the object, but not before.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are asking too much of the eyedropper.

I propose you another solution: change the default Graphic Style to the one you want to use.

- Add the **Graphic Style** to the **Style Panel**
- Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, drag your style to the **Default Style** to replace it

[image: animation showing recommended procedure]

You can change the Default Graphic Style as many times as you want, and from then on, every new shape you create will have that style.